# SUVAT Maths don't add up in SpriteKit's physics engine (iOS - Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, skphysicsbody, physics-engine

I am using SpriteKit's built in Physics Engine to build a game for iOS. Basically it involves a bouncing ball which moves via me manually setting it's initial velocity and bounces via resetting the velocity within the contact event with the floor.

The issue is, the actual maths for this environment do not add up. Using 'SUVAT' equations it's easy to determine how far the ball's x-displacement should be when it reaches the floor after being thrown with a certain velocity, however (with gravity set to -9.81), it barely moves a couple of pixels.

I simplified the problem to just trying to shoot a ball a certain distance upwards (in the y-direction) and the same thing happened, it moves a couple of points up and then just falls to the floor, at least a 20th of how far it should move.

This is how I have set the physics environment up:

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -9.81);
```

And then this is my function for generating this ball (shooting upwards) example. Mathematically it should reach the height of the tower:

```
-(void)generateTestBall {
self.ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball"];
SKSpriteNode * tower = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];
self.ball.position = CGPointMake(self.scene.size.width/2,self.scene.size.height/2);
self.ball.size = CGSizeMake(20,20);
self.ball.color = [SKColor redColor];
self.ball.colorBlendFactor = 1;

tower.position = CGPointMake(self.scene.size.width/2 + 20,self.scene.size.height/2+100);
tower.size = CGSizeMake(20,200);
tower.color = [SKColor blueColor];
tower.colorBlendFactor = 1;
[self addChild:tower];
[self addChild:self.ball];

self.ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
self.ball.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
self.ball.physicsBody.linearDamping = NO;
self.ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
CGFloat ballVel = sqrt(2*9.81*tower.size.height);
NSLog(@"%f",ballVel);
self.ball.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, ballVel);
```

}

Please can someone explain what I am doing wrong? I've double checked my maths (I'm a maths student so fingers crossed that's not the issue)!

Thanks!
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I FINALLY managed to figure it out. Just incase anyone else is experiencing the same issue I'll post the answer here:

The issue was that, although gravity is (apparently) in ms^-2 and velocity m2^-1 (to replicate earth), any distances in Objective C are measured in POINTS rather than the required form of METRES. Therefore any calculation done with x,y position / size values taken from SKSpriteNodes etc will be a certain factor out.

After running a few tests I found the factor to roughly be 157. This means that you must multiply any sizes / distances in POINTS by 157 to get the relative 'METRE' value which will work with SUVAT.

The actual numbers themselves seem a bit ridiculous as they're all very big (velocity, distance etc) but that doesn't actually pose a problem anyway as they all now work relative to each other!

Hope this helps anyone!
Steve